# how to include path of a directory containing files inside bash script

Tags: bash, path

I am writing a bash script that will get the user defined filenames and then use alsa to play that file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/Documents/audio
read -p "Enter a filename: " filename
aplay $filename
```

Above is what I have tried after reading about how to include path in a script. But at the terminal prompt, after I do `./script.sh`, it returns no such a file in the directory. I also tried `source ./script.sh` thinking that the environment is only changed in the subshell and it returns the same.

All I need is to include the path within this script and does not change the system path permanently.

I'd appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is used for finding programs, not data files. If you want `$filename` to be a file in the `audio` directory, you need to concatenate it explicitly.

```
#!/bin/bash
audiodir=/home/pi/Documents/audio
read -r -p "Enter a filename: " filename
aplay "$audiodir/$filename"
```

Comment: Ah, i did not know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the absolute path of the file that you're playing like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
AUDIO_PATH="/home/pi/Documents/audio"
read -p "Enter a filename: " filename
aplay "${AUDIO_PATH}/${filename}"
```